# Setting up a tinkerpop spark graph computer with DSE 4.7.1

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, titan, tinkerpop

I'm trying to test out using a spark graph computer with titan 1.0 and tinkerpop 3.0.1.

Now if I try the following steps the operation seems to work with a empty graph.

```
sparkgraph = GraphFactory.open('conf/hadoop-graph/read-cassandra.properties')

gs = sparkgraph.traversal(computer(org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.process.computer.spark.SparkGraphComputer))

gs.V().count()
```

The result if 0. Which makes sense as it is empty.

But if I create using the titan-cassandra-solr.properties field and populate it with some data just a few edges and vertices and then repeat the steps like above I get an error:

```
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Edge with id already exists: 143370
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.formats.util.TitanVertexDeserializer.readHadoopVertex(TitanVertexDeserializer.java:181)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.formats.util.GiraphRecordReader.nextKeyValue(GiraphRecordReader.java:46)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Edge with id already exists: 143370
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph$Exceptions.edgeWithIdAlreadyExists(Graph.java:1093)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerHelper.addEdge(TinkerHelper.java:57)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerVertex.addEdge(TinkerVertex.java:127)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.formats.util.TitanVertexDeserializer.readHadoopVertex(TitanVertexDeserializer.java:129)
    ... 13 more
```

I dont understand why it would be trying to create an edge. And by doing a query using the titan-cassandra-solr.properties config I cannot see this edge anyway.

If I've left out too many details, I'll be happy to update this question.

Comment: This magically just started happening to me on JanusGraph 0.20! It worked before, now it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by trying the same operation and a fresh graph on the latest build of Titan and TinkerPop just in case you're just hitting an indirect bug.  TinkerPop 3.1.1 has been out for a bit.  If that doesn't work I would even try building the Titan branch and the TinkerPop latest branch just to rule out an indirect bug.